# iterate through unicode strings and compare with unicode in python dictionary

Tags: python, unicode

I have two python dictionaries containing information about japanese words and characters:

1. vocabDic : contains vocabulary, key: word, value: dictionary with information about it
2. kanjiDic : contains kanji ( single japanese character ), key: kanji, value: dictionary with information about it

   Now I would like to iterate through each character of each word in the vocabDic and look up this character in the kanji dictionary. My goal is to create a csv file which I can then import into a database as join table for vocabulary and kanji.
   My Python version is 2.6
   My code is as following:

   ```
   kanjiVocabJoinWriter = csv.writer(open('kanjiVocabJoin.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
   kanjiVocabJoinCount = 1

   #loop through dictionary
   for key, val in vocabDic.iteritems():
       if val['lang'] is 'jpn': # only check japanese words
           vocab = val['text']
           print vocab
           # loop through vocab string
           for v in vocab:
                test = kanjiDic.get(v)
                print v
                print test
                if test is not None:
                   print str(kanjiVocabJoinCount)+','+str(test['id'])+','+str(val['id'])
                   kanjiVocabJoinWriter([str(kanjiVocabJoinCount),str(test['id']),str(val['id'])])
                   kanjiVocabJoinCount = kanjiVocabJoinCount+1
   ```

If I print the variables to the command line, I get:
vocab : works, prints in japanese
v ( one character of the vocab in the for loop ) : �
test ( character looked up in the kanjiDic ) : None

To me it seems like the for loop messes the encoding up.
I tried various functions ( decode, encode.. ) but no luck so far.
Any ideas on how I could get this working?
Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you use python 3 - its unicode is better

Comment: or, `from __future__ import unicode_literals` ?

Comment: thank you very much! Updating to python 3 solved the problem :D

Comment: There is a whole debate if python 3 "everything is unicode" is better or not so I wouldn't rush into some statement like Mark's. My opinion is that it's not better and unutbu response below is a far better approach. Python 2.x combined with a defaultencoding set to utf8 is a superior solution for managing unicode strings in python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From your description of the problem, it sounds like `vocab` is an encoded `str` object, not a `unicode` object.

For concreteness, suppose `vocab` equals `u'債務の天井'` encoded in `utf-8`:

```
In [42]: v=u'債務の天井'
In [43]: vocab=v.encode('utf-8')   # val['text']
Out[43]: '\xe5\x82\xb5\xe5\x8b\x99\xe3\x81\xae\xe5\xa4\xa9\xe4\xba\x95'
```

If you loop over the encoded `str` object, you get one byte at a time: `\xe5`, then `\x82`, then `\xb5`, etc.

However if you loop over the unicode object, you'd get one unicode character at a time:

```
In [45]: for v in u'債務の天井':
   ....:     print(v)    
債
務
の
天
井
```

Note that the first unicode character, encoded in `utf-8`, is 3 bytes:

```
In [49]: u'債'.encode('utf-8')
Out[49]: '\xe5\x82\xb5'
```

That's why looping over the bytes, printing one byte at a time, (e.g. `print \xe5`) fails to print a recognizable character.

So it looks like you need to decode your `str` objects and work with `unicode` objects. You didn't mention what encoding you are using for your `str` objects. If it is `utf-8`, then you'd decode it like this:

```
vocab=val['text'].decode('utf-8')
```

If you are not sure what encoding `val['text']` is in, post the output of

```
print(repr(vocab))
```

and maybe we can guess the encoding.

Comment: thank you very much for your long explanation! This helped me understand how python handles unicode. :)