# What does sys.maxunicode mean?

Tags: python, unicode

CPython stores unicode strings as either utf-16 or utf-32 internally depending on compile options.  In utf-16 builds of Python string slicing, iteration, and `len` seem to work on code units, not code points, so that multibyte characters behave strangely.

E.g., on CPython 2.6 with `sys.maxunicode` = 65535:

```
>>> char = u'\U0001D49E'
>>> len(char)
2
>>> char[0:1]
u'\uu835'
>>> char[1:2]
u'\udc9e'
```

According to the Python documentation, [`sys.maxunicode`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.maxunicode) is "An integer giving the largest supported code point for a Unicode character."

Does this mean that `unicode` operations aren't guranteed to work on code points beyond `sys.maxunicode`?  If I want to work with characters outside the BMP I either have to use a utf-32 build or write my own portable `unicode` operations?

I came across this problem in [How to iterate over Unicode characters in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494064/how-to-iterate-over-unicode-characters-in-python-3)

Comment: Interesting. On CPython 3.2.2 (Win x64), `sys.maxunicode` is `65535`...

Answer (score 5):

Characters beyond `sys.maxunicode=65535` are stored internally using UTF-16 surrogates.  Yes you have to deal with this yourself or use a wide build.  Even with a wide build you also may have to deal with single characters represented by a combination of code points.  For example:

```
>>> print('a\u0301')
á
>>> print('\xe1')
á
```

The first uses a combining accent character and the second doesn't.  Both print the same.  You can use `unicodedata.normalize` to convert the forms.