# len() with unicode strings

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

If I do:

```
print "\xE2\x82\xAC"
print len("€")
print len(u"€")
```

I get:

```
€
3
1
```

But if I do:

```
print '\xf0\xa4\xad\xa2'
print len("")
print len(u"")
```

I get:

```
4
2
```

In the second example, the len() function returned 2 instead of 1 for the one character unicode string u"".

Can someone explain to me why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2 can use UTF-16 as internal encoding for `unicode` objects (so called "narrow" build), which means  is being encoded as two surrogates: D852 DF62. In this case, `len` returns the number of UTF-16 units, not the number of actual Unicode codepoints.

Python 2 can also be compiled with UTF-32 enabled for `unicode` (so called "wide" build), which means most `unicode` objects take twice as much memory, but then `len(u'') == 1`

Python 3's `str` objects since 3.3 switch on demand between ISO-8859-1, UTF-16 and UTF-32, so you'd never encounter this problem: `len('') == 1`.

`str` in Python 3.0 to 3.2 is the same as `unicode` in Python 2.

Comment: How can I loop through an unicode character string that contains this kind of encoding? some thing like u"".

Comment: @lessthanl0l: Try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494064/how-to-iterate-over-unicode-characters-in-python-3